Create a custom codepage of unicode for ESC/POS thermal printer
I'm trying to printing Vietnamese on Thermal Printer with Java Android.
The printer not support Unicode or TCVN3. I'm using codepage 35: windows-1258 but it does not fully support the necessary characters for Vietnamese.
Is there any way to Create a custom unicode code page for ESC/POS thermal printers?
Thanks a lot for your help!
I tried using define user-defined characters but it didn't work
this.printer.rawCommand(new byte[] {
        0x1C, 0x2E, // cancelChineseCharModel
        0x1B, 0x25
});

byte[] cmd = new byte[5 + 37]; // Array size: 42 bytes, initialized to 0

cmd[0] = 0x1B; // ESC
cmd[1] = 0x26; // &
cmd[2] = 0x03; // y - height
cmd[3] = 0x41; // starting char to define, 'A'
cmd[4] = 0x41; // character to start with
cmd[5] = 12; // x1, dots in horizontal direction

int shift = 6;

// Fill the matrix as you wish..
// 'A' -> black square
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    cmd[i + shift] = (byte) 0xFF;
}
this.printer.rawCommand(cmd);```


Perhaps, these articles might be helpful. Is there a way to extend iconv to support more encodings?, iconv translit table of characters, Modifying encoding tables
